# i can not get the second 'id' to be recognized in the where property

Tags: php, html, sql

if i put a number where the second 'id' '=' 1 is in the where() part then it works for that row, but need it to be automatic for all the rows?

in the controller the code is:

```
 public function update()
     {
         $editproducts = DB::table('products')->get();
          $updates =  DB::table('products')
            ->where('id', '=', 'id')
        ->update([
            'plant' => request('plant'),
         'description' => request('description'),
         'price' => request('price'),
         'stock' => request('stock'),
         'created_at' => request('created_at')           
    ]);        
        return view('adminstock', compact(['updates', 'editproducts']));
}
```

on the page the code is:

```
                 <table class="table table-bordered">

                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>ID No</th>
                                    <th>Plant</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                     <th>Stock</th>
                                    <th>created on</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    @foreach($editproducts as $pro)

                                     <form method="post" action="editproducts">

                                       {{csrf_field()}}
                                   <tr>

                  <td><input class="bigger" type="text" name="id"  value="{{$pro->id}}" readonly /> </td>
                  <td><input class="bigger" type="text" name="plant"  value="{{$pro->plant}} "/> </td>
                  <td><input class="bigger" type="text" name="description"  value="{{$pro->description}} "/></td>
                   <td><input class="bigger" type="text" name="price"  value="{{$pro->price}} "/> </td>
                  <td><input class="bigger" type="text" name="stock"  value="{{$pro->stock}} "/></td>
                  <td><input class="bigger" type="text" name="created_at"  value="{{$pro->created_at}} "/></td>
                  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" > Edit </button></td>

                                      </tr>

                                    </form>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Why not just simply remove the `WHERE` condition entirely? Then every row will be updated.

Comment: Make the query work on plain SQL and then translate to PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing :

```
->where('id', '=', 'id')
```

to this:

```
->where('id', '=', $_POST['id'])
```